# Calling a C function from Python generated by SWIG, with char * output

Tags: python, c, types, swig

I'm new to SWIG and if my question is documented, feel free to just post the link and I'll read through it.

I have a C function that takes the form:

```
int myFunc(char *output, const char *input)
```

I generated the Python wrapper, and I tried calling this function (in Python) with:

```
m=""
n="valid input string"
myFunc(m,n)
```

This simply prints the (int) return code, and m is still "".  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking you probably need to pass `m` into the function with `byRef(m)` http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref

Comment: Keep in mind that a string in Python is immutable. Once you create it with `m=""`, you can't change the contents. You probably need to create a char array with ctypes, and pass that in "byRef", as Haz suggested. Or you could modify myFunc to allocate a char array and return that instead of an int.

Comment: Just to ask the stupid question, `myFunc()` actually, does something right? You validated that it's working?

Answer (score 1):

From the [SWIG manual section 8.3.4](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_nn12):

If your C function is declared like this:

```
int myFunc(char *myOutput, const char *myInput);
```

Then you can use the following SWIG interface syntax:

```
%include "cstring.i"

%cstring_bounded_output(char *myOutput, 1024);

int myFunc(char *myOutput, const char *myInput);
```

This should result in a Python wrapper function taking a single string argument (`myInput`) and returning a tuple of an integer (the C function's return value) and a string (`myOutput`). Memory for the string will be allocated by SWIG and be 1024 bytes in length, in this example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is not recommended practice (see my comment), and YMMV, but this seems to work for me with Python 2.4:

```
#pre-allocate enough space for m
m = "\x00"*100
n = "valid input string"
myFunc(m,n)
# now m.rstrip("\x00") has what you want
```